# Azure Active Directory and PHP Webapp on Azure - group users

Tags: php, authentication, azure, active-directory

I have a PHP Webapp page on MS Azure. I have made the page authenticate against Active Directory that is synced to Azure.

I have looked everywhere and I cannot find the answer to the following question:

How do I limit the access to my webapp to a particular person or group in my Active Directory? Or at least, can someone point me in the direction that I should look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on that idea and just made a table with an additional username and password access.

And created a session to store it.